# AngularJS - Export PDF/CSV from ui-grid giving error

Tags: angularjs

Hi I follow the same procedure as mentioned in the plunker below
[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/y6H6aJO08QN1hcTlh2mJ?p=info)

Its working fine as expected. but I just added the below code to export data from the table after the gridOptions like below, giving error gridApi is not defined, please suggest, but without `init()`/`then()` in simple controller export is working

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
    paginationPageSize: 25,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    rowTemplate : 'rowTemplate.html',
    columnDefs: [
      { name: $scope.translate.EQUIPMENT_NAME, field: 'equipmentName' },
      { name: $scope.translate.EQUIPMENT_TYPE, field: 'equipmentType.equipmentType' },
      { name: $scope.translate.CREATION_DATE, field: 'creationDate' },
      { name: $scope.translate.ACTION, cellTemplate:'cellTemplate.htm'}
    ],
      exporterSuppressColumns: [ $scope.translate.ACTION ],
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
     console.log('grid table fun');
      //currentSortColumns = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].field;
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      //$scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, $scope.sortChanged );
      //$scope.sortChanged($scope.gridApi.grid, [ $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0] ] );
      gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
        paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
        paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
        //$scope.sortChanged($scope.gridApi.grid, currentSortColumns );
        getPage();
      });  
    }
  };
    $scope.export = function(){
         //alert("hii");
    console.log($scope.export_format);
    if ($scope.export_format == 'csv') {
      var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
      $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( $scope.export_row_type, $scope.export_column_type, myElement );
    } else if ($scope.export_format == 'pdf') {
      $scope.gridApi.exporter.pdfExport( $scope.export_row_type, $scope.export_column_type );
    };
  };
```

Comment: Hi @luxor001 suggest please

Comment: Error: $scope.gridApi is undefined
$scope.export@file:///D:/DB/Angular-js.......